# Bayesian Model Suddenly Overfits

Tags: bayesian, overfitting

I am building a Bayesian model and have a trouble of (sudden) overfitting. The example figure that shows the issue is here:[image]

Until around 1250 iteration, the log-likelihood goes up little by little, but it soon starts increasing rapidly, which might be a sign of overfitting.

I'm building a language model, so the strangeness of this log-likelihood is clearer if we check perplexity.
[image]

Perplexity is defined as $${\rm Perplexity} = p( \mathbf{w} | \mathcal{M}) = \exp \left( \frac{-{\rm loglik}}{{\rm Num\ obs.}} \right),$$
which means the probability of observing words $\mathbf{w}$ under the model $\mathcal{M}$.

Perplexity can be interpreted as the geometric mean of possible choices of words, and the model works well if the perplexity is low. My model's perplexity is almost $0$ and model works "too" well.

**My questions are,**

1. Does overfitting occur in the full Bayesian model? (no optimization, and all parameters including hyper-parameters are estimated using MCMC sampling)
2. What can I do to fix the model?

Comment: Is it possible that your MCMC chain (s?) have simply not converged? Could either be numerical issues,  the sampler going off to wherever after getting into an unfortunate region of the posterior or moving from an initial low likelihood region (temporarily) into a high likelihood region.